# How to do it so that rails3-jquery-autocomplete can list words separated by spaces as separate tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed this gem: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

and applied it successfully:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :name
end
```

I have a Tag model and I separate tags with a space in a `tag!` method:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tags_attributes

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  def tag!(tags)
    tags = tags.split(" ").map do |tag|
      Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag)
    end
    self.tags << tags
  end
end
```

(It has a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation with the Post model).

I created a post with these two tags: `food` `drink`.

Now the problem is that it autocompletes like this:

```
food
food drink
```

when I type *food*.

I want it to auto complete like this:

```
food
```

(when I type *food*)

and

```
drink
```

(When I type *drink*)

Any suggestions to fix this?

**EDIT:**

I'm starting to suspect that the gem is not working and this is the browser's autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you didn't mention any model name in the

```
autocomplete :name
```

I think it should be like this , if you are using tag model to get name of tags

```
autocomplete :tag , :name
```

Also it will be helpful for you , to see the request in browser console . It shows the status of request .
Thanks